# How can I get my ItemsControl on a xaml form to stretch to fit the grid cell?

Tags: xaml, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to get my ItemsControl to expand to fit the grid column it is in.

This is what I'm trying to get:
[image: what I want]

This is what I'm actually getting:
[image]

I've tried StackPanel, ViewBox, WrapControl from Microsoft.ToolKit.Uwp.Controls and setting HorizontalAlignment to stretch.

I've tried converting it to a ListView.

Here's my xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="PaymentScreen.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:PaymentScreen"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.DataContext>
        <local:PaymentVM></local:PaymentVM>
    </Page.DataContext>

    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.10*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.80*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.10*"></ColumnDefinition>

        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.15*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.30*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.65*"></RowDefinition>

        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.66*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.33*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1"></Border>
            <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1"></Border>



                <ItemsControl Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.PaymentEntryLines}" >

                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>

                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>

                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:PaymentLine" >
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <TextBox Grid.Row="0"  Text="To Pay:"></TextBox>
                                <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{x:Bind AmountToPay, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
                                <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Text="Paid:"></TextBox>
                                <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Text="{x:Bind AmountPaid, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
                            </Grid>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>



            <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
            <StackPanel>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBox Grid.Row="0"  Text="To Pay:"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="300.10"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Text="Paid:"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Text="500.40"></TextBox>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>

            </Border>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: The ItemsControl is behaving as if it has HorizontalAlignment="Left"; is there possibly an implicit style somewhere that might be setting that? What if you add HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" to the ItemsControl? That is the default for a child of a grid (you can see that's the case with the two red-edged borders), but try it explicitly just to see.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I added HorizontalAlignment="Stretch", but nothing changed. (If I set it to "Right", it moves it to the right of the cell.) I set MinWidth="250" on the grid inside the DataTemplate, which got it closer to what I want, but I need it to be a percentage, so that it works on different screen sizes.

Comment: Can you use a UniformGrid in UWP? In WPF you would fix this by replacing the StackPanel in your ItemsPanelTemplate with `<UniformGrid Rows="1" />` -- it'll put the children in columns, and stretch them to fill itself. But IIRC UWP doesn't have that control. Some people [seem to think this works](https://github.com/rickapps/UWP-UniformGrid-Control) but I haven't tried it.

Comment: But anyway: The problem isn't that the ItemsControl isn't stretching; set its Background to Red and you'll see it is. The problem is that its *children* aren't stretching.

Comment: I see what you mean about its children not resizing to fill it. I need a control whose orientation I can set to horizontal and whose children will resize to fit the available space. UniformGrid is not available in UWP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is an equivalent of the WPF `UniformGrid`, which divides its client area evenly among its children: Set `Rows="1"` and it arrange the children horizontally:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <somens:UniformGrid Rows="1" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

[Here is a frequently-recommended UWP implementation of `UniformGrid`](https://github.com/rickapps/UWP-UniformGrid-Control).

Comment: I'm getting errors: The property 'AncestorType' was not found in type 'RelativeSource' and The property 'ElementName' was not found in type 'RelativeSource'.

Comment: VisualTreeHelper is supported. It's objecting to:  contentPresenter.SetBinding(TotalAvailableActualWidthProperty,
               new Binding("ActualWidth") { Source = panel });. The error is 'Binding does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments'. I tried to work round it with:   Binding myBinding = new Binding();
                myBinding.ElementName = "ActualWidth";
                myBinding.Source = panel;
                
                contentPresenter.SetBinding(TotalAvailableActualWidthProperty,
                    myBinding);   This runs ok but nothing changes.

Comment: I tried the updated version, but it doesn't make any difference. I've put my mini project on dropbox just in case I'm doing something stupid. https://www.dropbox.com/s/gqborjhurtqzgg9/PaymentScreen.zip?dl=0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160729/discussion-between-gail-bowen-and-ed-plunkett).

Comment: Thank you so much for telling me about https://github.com/rickapps/UWP-UniformGrid-Control